# Is there any way to obtain place of a special character in a string by means of the pre build search method of a string?

Tags: javascript

Ok I would like to find out the place of a special character in order to trim a string from there. I works with a normal letter but it doesn't seem to work with characters like |

```
'Yeezy Boost 700 Analog | EG7596'.search('a') 
>>>  18
'Yeezy Boost 700 Analog | EG7596'.search('7') 
>>>  12 
'Yeezy Boost 700 Analog | EG7596'.search('|')
>>> 0
```

why

Comment: I haven't visited stackoverflow in a while never got downvoted before , I need to understand why my question was downvoted , did I do something wrong? I only would like to understand so i can LEARN from this and maybe ask better next time?

Answer (score 2):

MDN states that you need to use [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search). However, if you use a string it gets converted to a regexp:

> **Parameter:** A regular expression object. If a non-RegExp object obj is passed, it is implicitly converted to a RegExp by using new RegExp(obj).

Since `|` is a special character in a Regex expression, it isn't a valid search. So, to get this working you need to escape the pipe.

```js
// As a string you need to escape the escape operator with two '\\'
console.log('String Search:', 'Yeezy Boost 700 Analog | EG7596'.search('\\|'))

// As a regex you only need to escape once
console.log('Regex Search:', 'Yeezy Boost 700 Analog | EG7596'.search(/\|/))
```

Answer (score 1):

search() expectes a regular expression, '|' has a special meaning in regular expressions. [Read more on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/suchen)

What you want to use is [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```
'Yeezy Boost 700 Analog | EG7596'.indexOf('|')
>>> 23
```

Comment: Why can't OP use `search()` with an escaped `|`?

Comment: He can but I it seems that he doesn't want to search for a regex. That's why I advised to use indexOf()

Comment: So why not just give an example of searching the way they were?  They're asking what's wrong with their code, not how to use a different method.  See below for the correct answer.